# Ignoring some attributes when caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6 app, I'm adding some caching to the list of users.

Currently, my code looks like

```
# users/index.html.erb

<table>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @users %>
  </tbody>
</table> 

# users/_user.html.erb

<% cache(user)do %>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= user.name %>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= user.status %>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The caching works but the fragments are invalidated whenever the `updated_at` attribute changes.

However, to optimize it, I'd like to invalidate it only when one of the displayed attribute changes. For instance, I don't want a new fragment when the user updates her own password.

What is the preferred way to achieve so? The code below seems to work but I'd like to make sure it doesn't have dropbacks.

```
<% cache [user.name, user.status] do %>
```

Is that the preferred way also when including in the key multiple attributes? I.e.

```
   <% cache [user.name, user.status, user.email, user.role, user.whatever] do %>
```

Moreover, let's say I want to cache the entire table. Which key should I use? `@users` doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `cached: true` when you render the `@users` collection https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#collection-caching

I don't really see the point on optimizing the individual user cache at that level of optimization (how often whould a user modify its password or another non important attribute?). I don't think that not having that optimization has a real impact on your performance. Did you test that or you just want to do that? Don't overengineer things if you don't have to, I bet there are better things to optimize with more impact than that.

Comment: Thanks. Users will update their password every 3 months. That is a regulatory requirement. While the other attributes will almost never change.

Comment: Preventing that 1 query every 3 months doesn't sound like it's worth the effort of doing it. Personally I wouldn't do that, it's up to you but I bieet you'll have a lot of better places to improve performance with much more impact before getting to that specific user cache.